Not Able to Intigrate with Phonepe Qr Code
When phonepe qrcode scan Transaction Note not received Automatic
by default Received "Payment From PhonePe", I want Invoice no is a Transaction Note
Only Phonepe not support other app eg, Gpay,Amazon,paytm is supported
Please guide
i trying  "tn=" it will be working perfect in Gpay,Amazon,Paytm but not supported with Phonepe

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
